# Websocket closed with status code: 1011 - ASP.NET CORE with Angular 10

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket

## **Here is the log (console browser)**

```
[2020-11-26T11:40:56.352Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.353Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.
Utils.js:224 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.402Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:8080/upload-process?id=14Cj6nHlbbp1RJX6GnO0fA.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.403Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.403Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.404Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 39.
Utils.js:224 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.405Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'messagepack'.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.469Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) socket closed.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.469Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().) called while in state Connected.
Utils.js:218 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.469Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().'.
push../node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/Utils.js.ConsoleLogger.log @ Utils.js:218
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.470Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().) called while in state Connecting.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.470Z] Debug: Hub handshake failed with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().' during start(). Stopping HubConnection.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.471Z] Debug: Call to HttpConnection.stop(Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().) ignored because the connection is already in the disconnected state.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T11:40:56.471Z] Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 ().'.
```

*obs: I have the same log on JavaScript (PoC).*

## **Angular 10**

packages: "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.0",
"@microsoft/signalr-protocol-msgpack": "^5.0.0",

```
export class SignalRService extends BaseService {
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  private signalrUrl = `${this.environment.apiUpload}upload-process`;
  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  public connect = () => {
    this.startConnection();
    this.addListeners();
  }

  private getConnection(): HubConnection {
    return new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.signalrUrl)
      .withHubProtocol(new MessagePackHubProtocol())
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
      .build();
  }

  private startConnection(): any {
    this.hubConnection = this.getConnection();

    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(() => console.log('connection started'))
      .catch((err) => console.log('error while establishing signalr connection: ' + err))
  }

  private addListeners(): any {
    this.hubConnection.on('ProcessUpload', (data: any) => {
      console.log('message received from API Controller ProcessUpload');
      console.log(data);
    });

  }
}
```

## **API(backend)**

- TargetFramework: netcoreapp3.1
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack" Version="5.0.0"

**Startup.cs**

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                       .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                       .AllowCredentials();
            }));
```

Configure

```
app.UseCors (option => option.AllowAnyOrigin ().AllowAnyMethod ().AllowAnyHeader ().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowCredentials());

app.UseEndpoints (endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllers ();
                endpoints.MapHub<UploadProcessHub>("/upload-process");
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

**I changed de versions on ASP.NET CORE**

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack" Version="5.0.0"

## TO

- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common": "3.1.0.0",
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core": "3.1.0.0",
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "3.1.0.0",
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json": "3.1.0.0",
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "3.1.0.0",
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "3.1.0.0",

LOG:

```
[2020-11-26T13:06:02.963Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:02.965Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:02.967Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://localhost:5001/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.167Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.169Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting.
Utils.js:224 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.231Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:5001/chatHub?id=d28Y5uTKpz4FYGaSqf6k6Q.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.232Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.233Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.235Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 32.
Utils.js:224 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.236Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.283Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 3.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.285Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:04.285Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
signalir.service.ts:33 connection started
Utils.js:228 [2020-11-26T13:06:12.747Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 59.
signalir.service.ts:39 message received from API Controller ProcessUpload
```